# Marshalling error on WebFault

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

I have the following classes:

```
@WebFault(faultBean="com.myapp.FaultBean", name="MyWSException", targetNamespace = "exception.myapp.com")
    public class MyWSException extends RuntimeException {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5911956366562576341L;

        private FaultBean faultBean;

        public MyWSException(String message, FaultBean faultBean) {
            super(message);
            this.faultBean = faultBean;
        }


        public MyWSException(String message, Throwable cause, FaultBean faultBean) {
            super(message);
            this.faultBean = faultBean;
        }

        public FaultBean getFaultInfo() {
            return faultBean;
        }
    }
```

And this is my FaultBean:

```
@XmlType(name="WSFaultType", namespace = "exception.myapp.com")
@XmlRootElement(name="MyWSException")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public final class FaultBean {


    @XmlElement(name="message", required=true)
    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name="code", required=true)
    private String code;

    public FaultBean(){
        super();
    }

    public FaultBean( String message, String code) {
        super();
        this.message= message;
        this.code = code;
    }



    public final String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public final void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message= message;
    }

    public final String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public final void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

Now I have two AOP classes, one to capture all my custom exceptions, and an additional one to capture Spring's exceptions when committing my transactions, in order to catch all unexpected errors of my persistence layer:

```
@Aspect
public class SpringExceptionAspect {


    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private final void anyPublicOperation() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(void org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager.commit(*))")
    public final void anyTransactionError() {
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "anyPublicOperation() && anyTransactionError()", throwing = "error")
    public void catchException(JoinPoint jp, Throwable error) {
           FaultBean bean = new FaultBean(error.getMessage(), "ERRCODE");

        throw new MyWSException("Persistence error:", bean);
    }
}


@Aspect
public class CustomExceptionAspect{


    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private final void anyPublicOperation() {
    }

    @Pointcut("within(com.myapp.service..*)")
    public final void anyServerMethod() {
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "anyPublicOperation() && anyServerMethod()", throwing = "error")
    public void catchException(JoinPoint jp, Throwable error) {
            FaultBean bean = new FaultBean(error.getMessage(), "ERRCODE");

            throw new MyWSException("Error:", bean);
    }


}
```

Now when Exceptions get caught in the second Aspect (when I throw my custom exceptions), everything works and I get the expected soap:fault response. However when Spring's own Transaction exceptions are caught, I get this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring
Marshalling Error: neither class com.myapp.FaultBean nor any of its superclasses are known to this conext</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If they are the same classes, how can this be happening? Why is Jax-b able to marshall those from one point but not from the other one?